Issue with hp.x Quantum ESPRESSO Calculation on HPC System
I am trying to run an hp.x Quantum ESPRESSO calculation on an HPC system, but the output is not as expected. The scf calculation runs without any issues. However, when I increase the number of CPUs to run hp.x, problems arise.
This is the bash file:
#SBATCH -J hp
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=50
#SBATCH --partition=compute
#SBATCH --time=36:00:00
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --mem=100GB

# Load QuantumESPRESSO module
module load QuantumESPRESSO/7.1-foss-2022a

# Set the number of OpenMP threads
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMPI_MCA_btl='^uct,ofi'
export OMPI_MCA_pml='ucx'
export OMPI_MCA_mtl='^ofi'
export OMPI_MCA_btl=^openib


# Run QuantumESPRESSO
mpirun hp.x -in hpn.in > hpn.out

Here is the hpn.in:
   prefix='NiO',
   outdir='./out',
   nq1 = 8, nq2 = 8, nq3 = 8,
   conv_thr_chi = 1.0d-8,
   iverbosity = 2
/

And this is what I get in hpn.out file:
slurm-compute-h22d5-u14-svn3:rank141.hp.x: Failed to modify UD QP to INIT on mlx5_0: Operation not permitted
slurm-compute-h22d5-u14-svn3:rank149.hp.x: Failed to modify UD QP to INIT on mlx5_0: Operation not permitted
slurm-compute-h22d5-u14-svn3:rank149.hp.x: Failed to modify UD QP to INIT on mlx5_0: Operation not permitted
slurm-compute-h22d5-u13-svn4:rank49.hp.x: Failed to modify UD QP to INIT on mlx5_0: Operation not permitted
.
.
.

I already found in a forum that I have to add those lines bellow to the bash file and I already did but the problem persist
export OMPI_MCA_btl='^uct,ofi'
export OMPI_MCA_pml='ucx'
export OMPI_MCA_mtl='^ofi'
export OMPI_MCA_btl=^openib

Could someone tell me where this problem originates from and how can I fix it please?
